# Bash find and -exec returns illegal byte sequence

Tags: bash

My goal is to replace `str-a` with `str-b` in all the files in the folder src.

I tried:

```
find src -type f -exec sed -i "" 's/a-table/chi-table/g' {} +
```

As a result, I get this error:

`sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Would suggest removing `""` and quoting the filename, e.g. `'{}'`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...whether `sed -i ""` is correct depends on which platform one is on; on some BSDs (including MacOS) the suffix argument after `-i` is mandatory. And an unquoted `{}` is valid in bash, though it may be a problem in some other shells.

Comment: Good advice, thank you @CharlesDuffy. I'm always a bit cloudy on mac use and quote out of habit to ensure no issues regardless of OS...

Comment: •nod*. What's relevant here is that it's `find` honoring the `{}` substitution, which it does *after* the shell has invoked it; so one doesn't need to worry about how the filename would be parsed unquoted, but only about how the currently-active shell will treat the string `{}` unquoted.